# Captcha image "broken" on webhost but not on localhost

Tags: php, captcha

I have a captcha script that should generate a code. It works brilliantly on my localhost, but when I upload it to my webhost it just looks like a broken image. Mind you, GD is installed and working (I have an image resizing script that works fine on the webhost).

Here's my code for captcha.php (the captcha session value is generated outside this script):

```
<?php header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); ?>
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php

$text = $_SESSION['captcha'];

//Image specs
$fontsize = 28;
$imagewidth = 130;
$imageheight = 50;

$image = imagecreate($imagewidth, $imageheight);
imagecolorallocate($image, 75, 146, 178);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

//Set fonts
$font1 = 'fonts/font1.ttf';
$font2 = 'fonts/font2.ttf';
$font3 = 'fonts/font3.ttf';

//Create 15 random lines
for ($x=1; $x<=15; $x++) {
    $linecolor = imagecolorallocate($image, 206, 228, 244);
    $x1 = rand(1,110);
    $y1 = rand(1,50);
    $x2 = rand(1,110);
    $y2 = rand(1,50);
    imageline($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $linecolor);
}

//randomize font
$randfont = rand(1,3);
if ($randfont == 1) { 
    $font = $font1; 
} elseif($randfont == 2) { 
    $font = $font2; 
} else {
    $font = $font3;
}

//Randomize text angle
$angle = rand(-3,3);

imagettftext($image, $fontsize, $angle, 10, 32, $textcolor, $font, $text);
imagejpeg($image);

?>
```

Any idea what might be causing this strange behaviour?

Comment: did you upload `fonts` folder ?

Comment: could you change the content header for testing and debug purposes to text/html, so you might be able to get an error message.

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled? Any errors in your logs? Maybe there's a conflict with the session and headers being sent.

Comment: Thanks safarov, got it working now. Fonts were uploaded but named incorrectly. =( Silly me. Sorry for all your trouble!

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix. You're probably running lamp on linux. this happened to me because my lamp didnt have the gd module. Gd (graphic something) is the module that renders the captcha picture on the fly. to fix it go to the terminal at your lamp server and type:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

you should be good to go